What is the intuition of the Conley-Zehnder index of a Reeb Orbit?
Given a path of symplectic matrices starting at the identity, the Conley-Zehnder index is essentially defined as twice the winding number plus some "correction" term if the path is not a closed path, but I do not understand where is the correction term coming from.
For example, if one computes the Reeb flow on the boundary of an ellipsoid $E(a,b,c)$ (assuming $a < b < c$, and the ratios of these radii are irrational) it acts as a rotation by $2\pi t/a$ in one plane, and rotations by angles $2\pi/b$ and $2\pi/c$ on the other planes. Let $\gamma$ denote the shortest orbit of period $a$. Choosing the trivialization from $E(a,b,c) \subset \mathbb{C}^3$ along $\gamma$, the linearization of the Reeb flow (along $\gamma$) yields a path $t\mapsto P(t)$ for $t \in [0,a]$, of symplectic matrices:
\begin{bmatrix}R_{2\pi t/a}&0&0\\0&R_{2\pi t/b}&0\\0&0&R_{2\pi t/c}\end{bmatrix}
and we can compute its CZ-index (i.e index of $\gamma$):

Since we achieve a full rotation on the first plane the index is just twice the winding number: 2

For the other two orbits, since $a < b < c$, the indices should be


$$CZ = 2 \times \text{Winding Number} + 1$$
Therefore, the index of $\gamma$ is
$$CZ(\gamma) = 2 + 1 + 1 = 4$$
Note we used the fact that $a/b$ and $a/c$ are less than one and irrational numbers.
I don't understand the "+1" in the computation of the indices for the second step.
(Edited)

I am not sure to understand your question. I imagine you take $\gamma$ to be 'the shortest orbit of period $a$' in 1. , but not in 2., where $\gamma$ is instead either the 'shortest orbit of period $b$' or 'of period $c$'. Is that right? But then, you sum the three CZ-indices to get the CZ-index along $\gamma$. Could you please clarify the setting here, and perhaps give a reference for your definition of the CZ-index and for these computations? Thank you.

I jus edited my question.The reference is Gutt's paper: The Conley-Zehnder index for a path of symplectic matrices

Thanks for your edits! Unfortunately I don't have much time to think about your question, but your might find some clues in Polterovich & Rosen's Function Theory on Symplectic Manifolds, where a 'quasi-CZ-index' is discussed. Vaguely speaking, the CZ-index computes (twice) the number of times a path 'goes through' a given direction; if the path only starts along that direction without returning to it, the path only 'went half through' the direction, hence twice*(half passing through) = 1. Since the periods $b, c >a$, the path only 'went half through' a given direction in those planes.
